# Is there any way to fit an image in a tab component

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, nimbus

I'm adding icons to tabs but i want the ImageIcon fits all the tabComponent.

[image]

I tried this code

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/itemtexto-off.png");
Image img = icon.getImage() ;  
Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance( 50, 25,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_DEFAULT ) ;  
icon = new ImageIcon( newimg );
tabbedPaneProductDetail.setIconAt(0, icon);
```

Also i tried this as a solution but not worked.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
label.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
tabbedPaneProductDetail.setTabComponentAt(1,label);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, i don't know if it's the proper one, thanks to @camickr

```
tabbedPane.setUI(new SynthTabbedPaneUI(){

Insets insets =new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

@Override
protected Insets getTabInsets(int tabPlacement,
                  int tabIndex){
                  return insets;
}

});
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found another solution setting this property

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab.contentMargins",  new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try playing with the UIManager. Add the following at the start of your program before you start creating component:

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.tabInsets", new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Of course not all LAF's may support this option. See [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks camickr ,don't work cause nimbus doesn't have that property, i found another solution but i don't know if it's the proper one, check my answer

Comment: `UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab.contentMargins",  new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));` i found this property in nimbus that helps

Comment: `TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTabArea.contentMargins`