# Java JButton only image?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I set the icon of my button to an .png I made in photoshop, but instead of just the image being visible, then there's still the button border or what ever you wish to call it.

[image]

I want the button to just be:

[image]

Comment: What Look&Feel are you using? You can remove borders, putting `Insets` in 0

Comment: This previous question may help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468169/is-there-any-way-to-fit-an-image-in-a-tab-component)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[there are set of methods implemented in API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) that created undecorated [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), e.g.

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setBorder(null);
//button.setFocusable(false);
button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button.setIcon(myIcon1);
button.setRolloverIcon(myIcon2);
button.setPressedIcon(myIcon3);
button.setDisabledIcon(myIcon4);
```

Answer (score 3):

You just missed a line.

i.e. `btn.setBorder(null);` is the only thing you need to do. Rest is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to make it perfect:`button.setFocusPainted(false);`

Comment: Can you expand on your answer a bit please?