# Set Bounds Not working in Java Swing for a Button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This program just creates a `UI1` and a `Button`. When I click on that button a new UI Appear which I coded so that it doesn't go outside the bounds of `UI1`. My main problem is that I'm trying to make the width and height of the button smaller so that it looks more like an app icon. But when I set the bounds on the button it doesn't change anything when I run the code.

```java
//Start
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainUI extends JFrame {//MainUI
    private JButton button;
    private JPanel panel;

    public MainUI() {

        //UI1
        setSize(1000, 700);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        try {

            //Here is the Button--
            button = new JButton();
            button.setBounds(200,200,70,70);
            Image img = ImageIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("icons8-messages-100.png")));
            button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            button.setFocusable(false);
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(button);
            add(panel);

            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                UI2 ui2 = new UI2();
                ui2.setLocationRelativeTo(panel);
                ui2.setVisible(true);

                ui2.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

                    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

                        //This makes the ui2 not go outside the Main UI
                        int x = ui2.getX();
                        int y = ui2.getY();
                        int width1 = getWidth();
                        int height1 = getHeight();
                        int width2 = ui2.getWidth();
                        int height2 = ui2.getHeight();

                        if (x < getX()) {
                            ui2.setLocation(getX(), y);
                        }
                        if (y < getY()) {
                            ui2.setLocation(x, getY());
                        }
                        if (x + width2 > getX() + width1) {
                            ui2.setLocation(getX() + width1 - width2, y);
                        }
                        if (y + height2 > getY() + height1) {
                            ui2.setLocation(x, getY() + height1 - height2);
                        }//end of if statements
                    }//componentMoved
                });//addComponentListener
            });//addActionListener
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something's Wrong");
        }
    }//End of MainUI

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainUI mainFrame = new MainUI();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}//Class MainUI

class UI2 extends JFrame {

    public UI2() {
        setBounds(getX() + 50, getY() + 50, 200, 200);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }
}//Class UI2
//End
```

Comment: sizing/locating of components is the  exclusive task of a layoutManager - __never-ever__ try to do it yourself, instead use a suitable manager, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/ BTW: please put some effort into formatting the code to make it readable (a code block needs at least 4 leading spaces, no tabs)

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice. I'm still new, I will try to make it more readable next time.

Answer (score 0):

`UI2` should be a [dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and not another `JFrame` since *Swing* applications should usually only have a single, [top-level container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).

You also don't need to do all the hard work yourself of placing GUI components on the screen nor sizing them. You should use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and other, relevant parts of the rich, [API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566772/java-jbutton-only-image) – in order to make the `JButton` look like an app icon.

More notes after the code.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainUI {
    private JButton button;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private UI2 ui2;

    public MainUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1000, 700);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try {
            button = new JButton();
            Image img = ImageIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("icons8-messages-100.png")));
            button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            button.setFocusable(false);
            button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button.setBorderPainted(false);
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(button);
            frame.add(panel);
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                if (ui2 == null) {
                    ui2 = new UI2(frame);
                }
                ui2.setVisible(true);
            });// addActionListener
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }// End of MainUI

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new MainUI());
    }
}// Class MainUI

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class UI2 extends JDialog {

    public UI2(JFrame owner) {
        super(owner);
        setSize(200, 200);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

                // This makes the ui2 not go outside the Main UI
                int x = getX();
                int y = getY();
                int width1 = owner.getWidth();
                int height1 = owner.getHeight();
                int width2 = getWidth();
                int height2 = getHeight();
                if (x < owner.getX()) {
                    setLocation(owner.getX(), y);
                }
                if (y < owner.getY()) {
                    setLocation(x, owner.getY());
                }
                if (x + width2 > owner.getX() + width1) {
                    setLocation(owner.getX() + width1 - width2, y);
                }
                if (y + height2 > owner.getY() + height1) {
                    setLocation(x, owner.getY() + height1 - height2);
                } // end of if statements
            }// componentMoved
        });// addComponentListener
    }
}// Class UI2
```

(Below notes are in no particular order.)

- You don't need to create a new `UI2` each time the user clicks the `JButton` (in `UI1`). Create it once and then just hide it when you close it and show it when you click the `JButton`. The default behavior is to hide the `JDialog` when it is closed.
- A *Swing* application does **not** need to extend `JFrame` (or `JPanel` or any other [JComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html)). A *Swing* application can extend `JComponent` (or subclass thereof) but it does not have to.
- The default layout for [the content pane of] `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` so no need to explicitly set this.
- Printing a message, like *Something's Wrong*, in a `catch` block, might be user-friendly but it won't help you find the cause of the [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)
  . I nearly always print the stack trace in my `catch` blocks.

Screen capture of running app.

[image: screen capture]

However, since you don't want `UI2` to move outside of `UI1`, an alternative would be to use a [JInternalFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) rather than a `JDialog`. Here is a demonstration.

(Again, there are notes after the code.)

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.DefaultDesktopManager;
import javax.swing.DesktopManager;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class IframTst {
    private JDesktopPane desktopPane;
    private JInternalFrame iFrame;

    public IframTst() throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createButton(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createDesktopPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(1000, 700);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButton() throws IOException {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton();
        Image img = ImageIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("icons8-messages-100.png")));
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.addActionListener(this::showIframe);
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }

    private JDesktopPane createDesktopPane() {
        desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        DesktopManager manager = new DefaultDesktopManager() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -4685522430190278205L;

            @Override
            public void dragFrame(JComponent f, int newX, int newY) {
                setBoundsForFrame(f, newX, newY, f.getWidth(), f.getHeight());
            }

            @Override
            public void setBoundsForFrame(JComponent f,
                                          int newX,
                                          int newY,
                                          int newWidth,
                                          int newHeight) {
                Rectangle rect = desktopPane.getVisibleRect();
                if (newX < 0) {
                    newX = 0;
                }
                if (newX + newWidth > rect.width) {
                    newX = rect.width - newWidth;
                }
                if (newY < 0) {
                    newY = 0;
                }
                if (newY + newHeight > rect.height) {
                    newY = rect.height - newHeight;
                }
                super.setBoundsForFrame(f, newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);
            }
        };
        desktopPane.setDesktopManager(manager);
        return desktopPane;
    }

    private void showIframe(ActionEvent event) {
        if (iFrame == null) {
            iFrame = new JInternalFrame(null, false, true, false, false);
            iFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            iFrame.setSize(200, 200);
            desktopPane.add(iFrame);
        }
        iFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new IframTst();
            }
            catch (IOException xIo) {
                xIo.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- The `ActionListener` is implemented using [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)
- The inspiration for keeping the `JInternalFrame` within the bounds of its parent `JDesktopPane` came from

> [Preventing JInternalFrame from being moved out of a JDesktopPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136944/preventing-jinternalframe-from-being-moved-out-of-a-jdesktoppane)

(as well as looking at the source code for class `DefaultDesktopManager`)

You can also set the initial location of the `JInternalFrame` within the `JDesktopPane`. Refer to

> [How do I open a JInternalFrame centered in a JDesktopPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488947/how-do-i-open-a-jinternalframe-centered-in-a-jdesktoppane)

How it looks when I run it.

[image: recording]